# valgrind-invalid read and write operations

Tags: c

1. i am trying to implement the perfect hash function for a given set of 0.1million unique keys.In the process of developing the code, iam getting the segmentation fault. The problem may be in insert_hash function.But being a beginner in C,iam unable to figure it out.Here is the complete code.

   ```
   # include<stdio.h>
   # include <stdlib.h>
   # define array_size 1000000
   /* Function to calculate x raised to the power y */
   int keys[1000000];
   unsigned long long p = 100000000019;
   int power(int x, unsigned int y) {
   if (y == 0)
       return 1;
   else if (y % 2 == 0)
       return power(x, y / 2) * power(x, y / 2);
   else
       return x * power(x, y / 2) * power(x, y / 2);
    }
    int rand_number() {
    //generate 9 digit random numbers with in range a and b;
    int a = 100000000, b = 999999999, num;
    num = rand() % (b - a + 1) + a;
    return num;
     }

    struct hash {
    int count, a, b, m;
    int *dyn_array;
    }*ptr[array_size], *tmp = NULL;
    void insert_hashkey(int hash1, int key) {
    int arraysize = 1, i, hash_value;
    static int primaryhashcount = 0, secondhashcount = 0;

       if (ptr[hash1]->count == 1) {
       primaryhashcount++;
       //ptr[hash1]=NULL;
       ptr[hash1]->dyn_array = (int*) malloc((sizeof(int)) * arraysize);
       if (ptr[hash1]->dyn_array == NULL) {
           printf("out of memory\n");
           exit(1);
       }
       ptr[hash1]->dyn_array[0] = key;
       printf("\n ptr[%d]->dyn_array[0]=%d  %d", hash1, key, primaryhashcount);
       } else {
       printf("\n entered in to else part");
       //ptr[hash1]=a;
       secondhashcount++;

       tmp = (struct hash*) malloc(sizeof(struct hash));
       tmp->m = (ptr[hash1]->count) * (ptr[hash1]->count);
       tmp->count = (ptr[hash1]->count);
       --(ptr[hash1]->count);
       arraysize = (ptr[hash1]->count) * (ptr[hash1]->count);
       //tmp=a;
       tmp->dyn_array = (int*) malloc((sizeof(int)) * arraysize);
       if (tmp->dyn_array == NULL) {
           printf("out of memory\n");
           exit(1);
       }
       tmp->a = rand_number();
       tmp->b = rand_number();
       for (i = 0; i < tmp->m; i++)
           tmp->dyn_array[i] = -1;
       for (i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
           if (ptr[hash1]->dyn_array[i] != -1) {
               hash_value = (((tmp->a) * (ptr[hash1]->dyn_array[i]) + tmp->b)
                       % p) % (tmp->m);
               printf("\n first if success");
               if (tmp->dyn_array[hash_value] == -1) {
                   tmp->dyn_array[hash_value] = ptr[hash1]->dyn_array[i];
                           secondhashcount, tmp->count, hash1, hash_value,
                           (ptr[hash1]->dyn_array[i]), tmp->m);
                }
            }

        }
       hash_value = (((tmp->a) * key + tmp->b) % p) % (tmp->m);
        if (tmp->dyn_array[hash_value] == -1) {
            tmp->dyn_array[hash_value] = key;
            printf(
                    "\n second hash count=%d count=%d ptr[%d]->dyn_array[%d]=%d,m=%d",
                    secondhashcount, tmp->count, hash1, hash_value, key,
                    tmp->m);
        } else
           printf("\n collision");
        free(ptr[hash1]->dyn_array);
        free(ptr[hash1]);
       ptr[hash1] = tmp;
       tmp = NULL;

      }
     }

    int hash_fun(int key, int a, int b, unsigned long long p) {
    int hash_val;
    hash_val = (((a * key) + b) % p) % 1000000;
    return hash_val;
     }
    void main() {
   int i = 0, hash1, count = 0, j;
    char ch;
    int a, b, m;
   time_t t;
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("input.in", "r");
   /* Intializes rand_num number generator */
   srand((unsigned) time(&t));

   for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {

       ptr[i] = NULL;
   }
   a = 774877719;
   b = 271009528;
   i = 0;
   while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &keys[i++]) == 1)
       ;
   printf("\n read keys successfully from file");
   //finding the hash values of array
   for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
       hash1 = hash_fun(keys[i], a, b, p);
       if (ptr[hash1] == NULL) {
           // create a structure of ni2 elements for each pointer where ni is the            number of collisions
           // printf("\nmaximum size=%d",malloc(MAX));

           ptr[hash1] = (struct hash *) malloc(sizeof(struct hash));
           if (ptr[hash1] == NULL) {
               printf("out of memory\n");
               exit(1);
           }
           ptr[hash1]->count = 1;
           insert_hashkey(hash1, keys[i]);

       } else {
           ++(ptr[hash1]->count);
           insert_hashkey(hash1, keys[i]);
       }
   }
    for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
       if (ptr[hash1] != NULL)
           free(ptr[hash1]);
   }
   }
   ```

2.the following is the report from valgrind. but iam unable to find exact problem in my code as everything appears correct for me after trying to fix for 6 hours.please help me in this context

```
  ==3595== LEAK SUMMARY:
  ==3595==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
  ==3595==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  ==3595==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  ==3595==    still reachable: 2,287,100 bytes in 190,411 blocks
==3595==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3595== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3595== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==3595== 
==3595== ERROR SUMMARY: 1026216 errors from 11 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==3595== 
==3595== 62 errors in context 1 of 11:
==3595== Invalid write of size 4
==3595==    at 0x8048A46: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x449be94 is 4 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==3595==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048807: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== 
==3595== 110 errors in context 2 of 11:
==3595== Invalid read of size 4
==3595==    at 0x8048976: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x439a804 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3595==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048807: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== 
==3595== 110 errors in context 3 of 11:
==3595== Invalid read of size 4
==3595==    at 0x8048955: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x439a804 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3595==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048807: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== 
==3595== 113 errors in context 4 of 11:
==3595== Invalid read of size 4
==3595==    at 0x80488C4: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x439a804 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3595==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048807: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== 
==3595== 457 errors in context 5 of 11:
==3595== Invalid read of size 4
==3595==    at 0x804889C: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x4487004 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3595==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048807: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== 
==3595== 3552 errors in context 6 of 11:
==3595== Invalid read of size 4
==3595==    at 0x8048A2C: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x425110c is 8 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3595==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048807: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== 
==3595== 3561 errors in context 7 of 11:
==3595== Invalid write of size 4
==3595==    at 0x8048957: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x425110c is 8 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3595==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048807: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== 
==3595== 3561 errors in context 8 of 11:
==3595== Invalid read of size 4
==3595==    at 0x8048929: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x425110c is 8 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3595==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048807: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== 
==3595== 14690 errors in context 9 of 11:
==3595== Invalid write of size 4
==3595==    at 0x8048864: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x4228b84 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==3595==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048807: insert_hashkey (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==    by 0x8048CEA: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== 
==3595== 999999 errors in context 10 of 11:
==3595== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3595==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048D29: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595==  Address 0x4e3b6b0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 20 free'd
==3595==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3595==    by 0x8048D29: main (in /home/abhimint/Desktop/hashing/a.out)
==3595== 
==3595== ERROR SUMMARY: 1026216 errors from 11 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use in valgrind: `--trace-origins=yes`
For each invalid read/write it will give you the function name where it happens.

invalid read means you're probably trying to read a variable that hasn't been initialized or that has been deleted.

Comment: i tried it and found that the problem is in insert_hash function.But iam unable to find the exact problem

Comment: It seems you're assuming ptr[hash1] is not null or nullptr in the function insert_hashkey.
Maybe try checking if it is NULL or nullptr

Comment: yes,it is returning null.but is there any situation where malloc cannot allocate the memory.if so,how to correct it

Comment: if (ptr[hash1]->count == 1) { <==
In this line you are assuming that it has been initialized with some data. I suggest you try checking before that line in the function if ptr [hash1] is not nullptr or NULL.

Maybe use an assert.. Try this for debugging. If it works than good if not then we'll have to think on the next check.

Comment: you are right that iam assuming ptr[hash1] holds some value. But in main function,  if (ptr[hash1] == NULL) {
            printf("out of memory\n");
            exit(1);  actually verifies for null, but the code is running without exiting giving segmentation fault
        }

Comment: are you running a 64 or 32 bit system?

Comment: 32 bit linux mint inside windows 7(64 bit).I tried it running in windows 7 also,there the programming is running till the end,but suddenly stops responding saying that it received signal trap

Comment: 32 bit means that the invalid read of size 4 could be an invalid read of a pointer. Does the program run all the way to the end?

Comment: in linux mint,the program is not running till the end.getting the segmentation fault in the middle. where as in windows, the program is unresponsive at the last. If it is an invalid read of pointer, what are the ways to correct it

Comment: write cout << "Something" <<endl; at the begining of the function. and run it on your linux. If it is printed before the segmentation fault then advance the cout to after the next line until it is no longer printed. Then you'll know which line causes the problem.